# Unsafe construction of an any type value for class

Tags: typescript, postgresql, eslint

I'm writing an app in typescript that connects to a PG data base (using the [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/) package).

I have this:

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.RED_USER,
  database: process.env.RED_DB,
  password: process.env.RED_PASS,
  port: Number(process.env.RED_PORT),
  host: process.env.RED_HOST,
});
```

Which generates the following error on the `new`:

```
ESLint: Unsafe construction of an any type value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)
```

Which is odd as my IDE infers the variable to have the `Pool` type. I've got the `@types/pg` package installed as well.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "index.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

What might be going on here? I didn't find any solution in my googling and am still new to typescript.